# PHP Admin does not accept password

Tags: wampserver

[This is what I keep getting when opening phpadmin.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqVqd.png)

I am writing this as a final try. I hope I find some help.
wamp server is installed correctly and the icon is green. The version is 5.3.10.
MySQL version is 5.5.20 and my Windows is 7 32-bits.

A few days ago I worked on phpadmin normally, then one day it decided to stop opening. It says:

> #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Following some answers that I found on the internet, I opened the config.inc 
and found the line of `[user]` and `[password]`. It was root and password is `''` (empty).

If I enter without a password I receive this message:

> Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)

But `AllowNoPassword` is true.

If I enter the password I get this message:

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

No matter if I enter the correct password or any other word. I changed user and password to admin and 12345, but it's no use. Is there some other file besides the config.inc where I should change user and password or what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Find this line `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']` in your config file and change to this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

Comment: WAMPServer's `phpMyAdmin` configuration comes with `auth_type` set to `'cookie'` by default

Answer (score 0):

As `phpMyAdmin` is setup to throw a login screen on WAMPServer you do not need to fiddle with `config.inc.php`

By default, the password for the `root` user account is blank so at the login screen you enter

```
Username = root
Password = [leave this blank]
```

If you have changed the password on the `root` account then of course you would use that password in the Password field.

> It sounds to me like you have installed another MySQL Server and this new MySQL Server instance is starting automatically.
>   This other MySQL Server may well have had a password set on the `root` user account and that is why you are getting this error.

Comment: yes it seems that this what happenned. the password in the config.inc and the password in the sql server are different.

Comment: You should not have a password in the `config.inc` file. Leave the password in there untouched i.e. `''`